# C# получить тип List

Tags: c#, list

на вход в функцию получаем объект IEnumerable list, допустим List<XClass>

```
private Type GetListType(IEnumerable list)
{
...
}
```

Как с получить тип листа (XClass)?

Если лист не пустой, то это делается вот так:

```
private Type GetListType(IEnumerable list)
{
  return list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

А с пустым не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что по-вашему пустой `list`? `null`? Тогда не получится, этой информации просто нету в данной точке.

А если просто `List<XClass>`, в котором `.Count == 0`, то ваш метод пройдёт.

Comment: Именно в котором Count==0

Этот метод возвращает:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XClass]]

А мне нужно просто получить XClass

Comment: @spart: Ну, прекрасно работает же: http://ideone.com/8Z0qig

Comment: Да, вы правы в этом примере все работает как часы, но у меня немного другой случай, вот я набросал в чем беда http://ideone.com/uLkfBx

Comment: @spart: Всё правильно: тип вашего `newList` — `List<List<string>>`. Проверка: http://ideone.com/hR96F7

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не туда смотрел :)

С меня плюс, как смогу ставить

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
private Type GetListType(IEnumerable list)
{
    return list.AsQueryable().ElementType;
}
```

Comment: отдает тип самого листа